# Problem with redis and php

Tags: php, redis

I'm pretty new to redis and Nosql databases in general. I have a few questions in my mind. I'm writing some codes to test out redis with the library Rediska and I want to see how redis stores the values in the database. 
I'm really confused my question is:

If I store  some values in the database, how can I access them through the redis cli? Is there any command that can list all the lists?

For example, I'm testing the retwitter app that comes with the rediska library:

```
$userData = $form->getValues();
$userData['id'] = User::fetchNextId();

// save user
$user = new User($userData['id']);
$user->setValue($userData);

$users = new Users();
$users->add($userData['id']);
```

After the last instruction, the userid is saved to the db. I want to query redis with its client to see it.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always check all keys stored in the database, using the [KEYS](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command (in this case, `keys *`).

After you find a key to inspect, using [TYPE](http://redis.io/commands/type) will retrieve the type of the key. Beware of case (i.e. `User` and `user` are different keys).

Based on the type, you now can filter the [full command list](http://redis.io/commands) to find the ones to issue against that type.

Now browsing the Rediska example, `Users` is a subclass of `Rediska_Key_Set`, so in Redis the structure is a `SET`. You can query sets using [these commands](http://redis.io/commands#set).

(for instance, `SMEMBERS [keyName]` will list all members of the set).

Finally, you can always call the `MONITOR` command in `redis-cli`, and then access the application. Every command issued against Redis will then be dumped on the screen.